# In Unity GUI, what a way to find out the Pixel Coordinate of RectTransform?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinates

[image]

I would like to know ScreenCoordinates through RectTransform of DivGraph seen in the picture above.

Here, the above ScreenCoordinates is, it refers to the same as the value that can be obtained through the Input.Mouse.Position like.

But no idea how.

Comment: find the pixel cordintate when a button is clicked?

Comment: this is the most difficult question in the universe.  if someone had a way to change between the various coordinates involving UI, they could be rich.